# background image not repeating in android layout

Tags: android

i've used the following code to repeat the image in the background but its not working can any one help?

Layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grass_bg"
    >
```

grass_bg.xml in drawable looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/grass_small"
        android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

its showing the same small image. its not repeating...

Comment: It works fine for me with the code your provided, is the layout in another layout or something?

Comment: https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/android-repeating-background-image/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a copy of `grass_bg.xml` for each time you use it (ie `grass_bg_2.xml`). This worked for me to assure the `tileMode` setting was not lost when the same background is used repeatedly.

Comment: Hey I've experienced similar odd issues that required renamed drawables to work around. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: It only Happened With me on Kindle

Answer (score 36):

Bitmaps (and their states) get reused a lot, and I've found it's easy to lose the tileMode if a BitmapDrawable is used in more than one place. The following code fixes the problem for me:

```
 public static void fixBackgroundRepeat(View view) {
      Drawable bg = view.getBackground();
      if(bg != null) {
           if(bg instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                BitmapDrawable bmp = (BitmapDrawable) bg;
                bmp.mutate(); // make sure that we aren't sharing state anymore
                bmp.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: It seems this bug is fixed in Honeycomb. This means the workaround is only needed in Gingerbread and earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately I can still see that problem on Jelly Bean. But very very rarely. I don't know how to actually trigger it. I only know that complex nested layouts seem to have an influence on it. Anyway, +1 because this solution here works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Janusz I just had this issue on Honeycomb (3.2 Galaxy Tab) so I'd say it's only needed in Honeycomb and earlier

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue but decided to investigate bit deeper. The cause was that I noticed one of my drawable works all the time, while the other is always broken. The trick is one image was made out of the another with just minior changes to colors and alpha. Drawables' XML is identical beside reference to the PNG. So I took pnginfo to see what's there.

**diagstripe_dark.png:**

```
Image Width: 18 Image Length: 30
Bitdepth (Bits/Sample): 8
Channels (Samples/Pixel): 3
Pixel depth (Pixel Depth): 24
Colour Type (Photometric Interpretation): RGB
Image filter: Single row per byte filter
Interlacing: Adam7 interlacing
Compression Scheme: Deflate method 8, 32k window
Resolution: 2835, 2835 (pixels per meter)
FillOrder: msb-to-lsb
Byte Order: Network (Big Endian)
Number of text strings: 0 of 0
```

**diagstripe_yellow.png:**

```
Image Width: 18 Image Length: 30
Bitdepth (Bits/Sample): 8
Channels (Samples/Pixel): 4
Pixel depth (Pixel Depth): 32
Colour Type (Photometric Interpretation): RGB with alpha channel
Image filter: Single row per byte filter
Interlacing: No interlacing
Compression Scheme: Deflate method 8, 32k window
Resolution: 2835, 2835 (pixels per meter)
FillOrder: msb-to-lsb
Byte Order: Network (Big Endian)
Number of text strings: 0 of 0
```

the diagstripe_yellow.png works, while diagstripe_dark.png does not, and if I replace references to it with reference to diagstripe_yellow.png, then it works (at least on 2.2.1 I got here) So the major differences are:

```
Channels (Samples/Pixel):
Pixel depth (Pixel Depth):
Colour Type (Photometric Interpretation):
Interlacing:
```

First try was to to disable interlacing, with no luck, even when header looks same:

**diagstripe_dark-2.png:**

```
Image Width: 18 Image Length: 30
Bitdepth (Bits/Sample): 8
Channels (Samples/Pixel): 4
Pixel depth (Pixel Depth): 32
Colour Type (Photometric Interpretation): RGB with alpha channel
Image filter: Single row per byte filter
Interlacing: No interlacing
Compression Scheme: Deflate method 8, 32k window
Resolution: 0, 0 (unit unknown)
FillOrder: msb-to-lsb
Byte Order: Network (Big Endian)
Number of text strings: 0 of 0
```

If anyone bothers to dig deeper here are the files: http://webnetmobile.com/files/ or use base64 tool to decode files from the quotes below:

**diagstripe_yellow.png:**

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAAeCAYAAAAhDE4sAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAAL
EwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9wCEg8JKbHU3pgAAAAdaVRYdENvbW1lbnQAAAAAAENyZWF0ZWQg
d2l0aCBHSU1QZC5lBwAAAE5JREFUSMdj7OnpqWdgYGCQft3S8FS0poFcNhM1DHkqWtPAuLxc4D+l
hjAwMDAwWwa2MIx6bdRro14b9dqo10a9Nuo1Gnstj4GBQYgSAwG9j8m8FwE2EgAAAABJRU5ErkJg
gg==
```

**diagstripe_dark.png:**

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAAeCAIAAAHZaentAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAAL
EwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9wCDww0GV3Ql5EAAAAdaVRYdENvbW1lbnQAAAAAAENyZWF0ZWQg
d2l0aCBHSU1QZC5lBwAAAGVJREFUOMvtkjsSgCAMRFfvfwOiV30WMCBqKFJIQ8XO/tgiAo6UAOUH
2ABJp5mqWri98B3ZXBmoogx0F4GX3w3LrQnZHju61Cfb6j15RqebG/23On/tHMiRkwheyxq5Rs4Z
aRZIXsBYcInPMeOmAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

**stripes.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:antialias="false"
    android:filter="false"
    android:src="@drawable/diagstripe_yellow"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Speak up if you got any further notes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try{ BitmapDrawable background = (BitmapDrawable) myView.getBackground();
    background.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); }
    catch(Exception e) { /*Do nothing; background is not BitmapDrawable; can be a color or null...*/ }
```